# Regular expression A-Z but then exclude string

Tags: regex

Really confused, got a bunch of addresses I need to process, I have an address line then a post code

The data is in the format:

```
ASHLEY CLOSE, HAVEN, BH1
```

I need to be able to get `ASHLEY CLOSE, HAVEN` then `BH1`.

I thought it would be something like:

```
/^([A-Z ,]+)(?!, BH)/
```

Comment: That matches the string only when it is *not followed* by `, BH` - which doesn't seem to be what you want. Try `(?=…)` instead

Comment: I don't know if you Need to think this complecated, to catch the postcode, if it is always 3 Digits at the end of the line this would even work `(...)$` to catch till last "," this would be enough `^(?:.*,)`. Of course this is simple trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ruby:

```
"ASHLEY CLOSE, HAVEN, BH1" =~ /^([A-| ,]+), ([A-Z0-9]+)/
 => 0 
> puts $1
ASHLEY CLOSE, HAVEN
 => nil 
> puts $2
BH1
```

I don't think you need an advanced regexp there.

Comment: Oh my that is amazing

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **very** basic example:

```
/(.+,) (BH.+)/gm

# match anything with one or more characters until a comma
# capture any number of these groups until you meet your BH block
# capture BH and the following character
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/xC0jB0

> Edit

[A better way](http://regex101.com/r/kK2cQ0) would be not to look specifically for "BH..." but to just match the group at the end of the string:

```
/^(.+,) (.+)$/gm
```